# Using GLM where one predictor is linear and one is logarithmic

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

I am fitting a GLM to binomial data with two independent variables, `a` and `b`. I have tried to fit a binomial GLM with the form `y~a+b+a*b`, so that I have the contributions of the two variables as well as an interaction term. This works OK, but in the data the effect of `b` is very gradual in comparison to `a`. The best fit I've tried by far is simply `y~a+log(b+1)+a*log(b+1)` (the +1 is because b=0 for some datapoints) with a binomial link function. Is it possible to use this as a GLM? It's just that I've not seen this done when I've searched online so I don't know if there's some good reason that people only seem to use polynomials. There is a question that seems related in a previous post [Interpret interactions and logarithms in linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78633/interpret-interactions-and-logarithms-in-linear-regression), but this was using a log-log function, and used `lm()` instead of `glm()`; so I'm not at all confident of the relation.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to transform predictors in a GLM (where possible, relying on some kind of theoretical justification). Consider if I handed you two predictors `a` and `d`, and you fitted `y=a+d+a*d` (in R notation, that's actually `y~a+d+a:d` or `y~a*d` for short). You'd be able to fit and understand that in terms of `a` and `d`,  even if I didn't tell you that `d` was just `log(b+1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to transform predictors in a GLM. Where possible, it would rely on some kind of theoretical justification.

Consider if I handed you two predictors `a` and `d`, and you fitted `y=a+d+a*d` **. You'd be able to fit and understand that in terms of `a` and `d`,  even if I didn't tell you that `d` was just `log(b+1)` (and if you don't know, GLM sure doesn't).

** (in R notation, that's actually `y~a+d+a:d` or `y~a*d` for short)

As for finding examples of transformation of predictors in GLMs, you need only look at the R help:

a) type `?glm` and scroll down to the bottom! The clotting example does exactly that.

b) the first example at `?predict.glm` is an example like my `a+d` example (ldose is log-dose, with the log being to base 2)